# Actionscript: How to show Mathematics formula in Flash Textbox?

Tags: math, actionscript-2, formula

How can I write mathematics formula in actionscipt2.0? As following:[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bc5fee2333.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bc5fee2333.png)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Mathmlformula project](http://code.google.com/p/mathmlformula/). They have a way to edit and display formulas and have their sourcecode available via SVN.

Comment: Yours is excellent. You use your own class? Right? How to write above equation not using own class. Sorry, I am newbie at flash that's why. Can you show me how to write the above equation?

Comment: It's not mine, I'm just someone who stumbled upon it some time ago. I'm afraid you'll have to do some source-digging yourself here.